# Get all employee with 1 year or more than experience

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been trying display all employees with their 1 or more year experience, but it keeps showing all, I'm using `DATEDIFF(YEAR,Hired_Date,GETDATE()) >= 1` in where clause but even with less that a year experience, it keeps showing.

Employee_Tb

```
ID   Hired_Date
001  2018-05-01
002  2018-03-01
003  2020-05-01
004  2019-12-05
005  2017-03-01
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee_Tb
WHERE Hired_Date < CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DATEDIFF(YEAR, EmpStartDate, GETDATE()) >= 1
```

shows the difference in calendar years. So 2019-12-31 and 2020-01-01 are 1 calendar year apart.

Depending on how precise you need it to be, you should probably use `month` instead of `year`.

Answer (score 0):

In your query you are using `EmpStartDate` instead of `Hired_Date`.

```
select *
from @T
where DATEDIFF(YEAR, Hired_Date, GETDATE()) >= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below query for SQL Server:

```
SELECT ID, Hired_Date
FROM Employee_Tb
WHERE (DATEDIFF(YEAR, Hired_Date, GETDATE())) >= 1;
```

If you want in MySQL you can use `TIMESTAMPDIFF` as below:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee_Tb WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, Hired_Date, CURDATE()) >= 1;
```

`TIMESTAMPDIFF` if you want the difference in MONTH you can change the YEAR to MONTH or DAY whatever need.

Comment: What about leap years?